# What capabilities are assigned to unauthenticated users?

Tags: capabilities

After reading the [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) article I can see that the Subscriber role has *read* capabilities only. What capabilities (if any) would be assigned to an unauthenticated user? i.e. a website visitor browsing around but not logged-in.

Answer (score 2):

Every user (loggedin or visitor) has the `exist` hardcoded capability.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/has_cap/

See line 745 in the source example.

Not logged in users have no other capabilities unless coded in a plugin or theme.

EDIT: GitHub link to the specific line on WP 6.3: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php#L810-L811

Comment: It's currently line 812, and thank you for this! Just saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Visitors have no capabilities. Not even the capability "read" which seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: According to [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#read) `read` gives most basic level of access to Dashboard, so it doesn't make sense for unregistered users either.

Comment: A I didn't check the codex for the `read` capability. Thought it would be something like read posts.

Comment: This is incorrect. Jory Hogeveen's answer is correct.